# How to set one of the fields displayed in the view to be a link to a webform submission?

Tags: 7, views

I'm using the Webform MySQL Views module to allow me to display webform submission data in views. This works really well; once you get it set up you work with the view just like you would a normal one.

So here's my question: how can I set one of the fields displayed in the view to be a link to the webform submission? There's an option to make a field a link in the Rewrite Results section:

[image]

But I'm not sure how to enter the path to the actual submission. The link I need to produce looks like this (copied from Content->Webforms->Submissions->View):

```
http://localhost/drool_calendar/node/1/submission/5
```

I'm guessing I don't need to specify the server or site name, but everything from `node/` on.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, so I expect you found your answer already.  You need to have the post's id number.  Try adding that field to the set, but excluding it from view.  Also, rearrange fields so it is earlier in the list than the field you are turning into the link.  You should then be able to use replacement tokens to make the path entry look something like:

/drool_calendar/node/[content:nid]/submission/[content:subid]

Starting the path with a / tells Drupal that you want this to stem from the site base url; discarding the leading slash tells Drupal you want this link to stem from the current page.